# Can I use the character "/" in awk

Tags: command-line, awk, xml

I am working with some .xml, and I have to extract part of them. I need to extract block between the line where appear `>21120352</PMID>` and the line where appears `</PubmedArticle>`

But the syntax of awk uses "/" so it gives me an error. I also have used the equivalent U+002F, but the solutions returns more than I want.

By the moment, I have this solution:

```
awk '/>21120352</,/PubmedArticle>/' file.xml
```

Also I have used the wildcard:

```
awk '/>21120352<.PMID>/,/<.PubmedArticle>/' file.xml
```

My question is if is possible to search using `</PMID>` and `</PubmedArticle>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` with a backslash: `\/`.

```
awk '/>21120352<\/PMID>/,/<\/PubmedArticle>/' file.xml
```

As an alternative to awk, I suggest to have a look at XMLStarlets `xml sel` function which is better in parsing XML files.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to escaping the pattern using a backslash `\` you can also use a variable to define your pattern:

```
awk '$0~pattern' pattern=">21120352</,/PubmedArticle>/" filename
```

*[More workarounds.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789643/search-pattern-containing-forward-slash-using-awk)*